# Eclipse doesn't start

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I newly installed eclipse form official Ubuntu repositories (`sudo apt install eclipse`). When I run it from launcher or terminal it doesn't start and show this error massage

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
```

and the log file content is :

```
!SESSION Mon May 28 17:52:17 IRDT 2018 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-05-28 17:52:18.099
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

```
$ dpkg --status eclipse
Package: eclipse
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 99
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 3.8.1-11
Depends: eclipse-jdt (>= 3.8.1-11), eclipse-pde (>= 3.8.1-11)
Description: Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE
 The Eclipse Platform is an open and extensible platform for anything and yet
 nothing in particular. It provides a foundation for constructing and running
 integrated software-development tools. The Eclipse Platform allows tool
 builders to independently develop tools that integrate with other people's
 tools so seamlessly you can't tell where one tool ends and another starts.
 .
 This package provides the whole Eclipse SDK that contains Eclipse Platform,
 Java development tools and Plug-in Development Environment, including source
 and both user and programmer documentation.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Orbital Alignment Team <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Homepage: http://www.eclipse.org/

$ apt-cache policy eclipse
eclipse:
  Installed: 3.8.1-11
  Candidate: 3.8.1-11
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.1-11 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

It does not give any other errors or warnings. I am on Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do to install and then run Eclipse, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for your comment. I just edit question. Hope it's clear know.

Comment: That was helpful. Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy eclipse` and `dpkg --status eclipse`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster edited.

Comment: So far so good. Did you ever install other Eclipse bundles on this Ubuntu installation? Could you please also add the output of `which -a eclipse` and `grep -iFe eclipse -R --include='*.desktop' /usr/share/applications /usr/local/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications` as well as the content of `/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/config.ini`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this error:

```
$ sudo snap install eclipse --classic  
error: snap "eclipse" has "install-snap" change in progress
```

Tried for long to resolve it and finally this worked out for me:

Run command:

```
$ snap changes
```

and check if its output says "Doing", something like this:

```
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready  Summary
92   Doing   today at 15:17 IST  -      Install "eclipse" snap
```

If yes, you can just abort this by using command :

```
sudo snap abort 92
```

where, 92 is ID.

Then, if you run install command again, it works fine.

```
sudo snap install eclipse --classic
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend for greater ease and comfort:

`sudo apt --remove purge eclipse`

or

`sudo apt --remove purge netbeans`

and install form SNAP:

`sudo snap install eclipse --classic`

or

`sudo snap install netbeans --classic`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing the Eclipse snap package which is also more up-to-date (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers version 4.7.3):

```
sudo snap install eclipse --classic
```

You can install snap packages alongside apt packages in order to try them, and afterwards remove the Eclipse apt package if you like the snap package better.